# How to create a pop up contact form in Node.js/Jade Template?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

How can I go about creating a form which pops up when the user clicks a button on a Jade template? I tried the following in HTML, which works:

http://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/

Now to use this in my Node.js project would I need to create a separate Jade file for the form itself? That is what I tried and then I tried to display the form like this:

```
function div_show() {
    alert("Test");
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work. What is the recommended approach for creating a pop up form in Jade? I am really confused with Jade and I can't seem to find a good tutorial for this, there are loads for HTML...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally for this you would use:
document.getElementById('abc').style.visibility="visible";
To hide your table use:
document.getElementById('abc').style.visibility="hidden";
When using the 'style' attribute you are using plain css commands. Make sure your default div style settings have it 'hidden', if that is what you want.
This display:block;visibility:hidden;' must exist in your default settings for that div style so the DOM has a clear path to what it is controlling. By itself 'display:block;' does not hide or make objects visible, it is mostly about the shape the div creates as a container for objects.
As an option you can use:
document.getElementById('abc').style.display="block";
To hide your table use:
document.getElementById('abc').style.display="none";
For this you would set your div style settings to 'display:none;visibility:visible;.
In this case 'display="none"' removes the object from all display layers and could allow other objects to fill in it's space. When it is visible it will push other objects on the same z-index out of the way. If it has a higher z-index, say +100 higher, it will pop-up above the other objects on the page.
 The 'visibility' attribute only controls the objects visibility, it does not remove it from the display memory. It can still take up space even though it is not visible. The 'opacity' attribute does about the same thing, except it allows you to also make an object as transparent as you like.